# Error to redraw in Tkinter Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a GUI that any time when the user press the button my app must clear canvas from all and draw same rect on it , It is work only for the first time .
The problem is : When user press the butten not for the first time i get the error messege:

```
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 2272, in create_rectangle
    return self._create('rectangle', args, kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 2251, in _create
    *(args + self._options(cnf, kw))))
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".61758520.61888032"
```

This is the way how I create the window to draw rects in :

```
rootWindow = Tkinter.Tk()
rootFrame = Tkinter.Frame(rootWindow, width=1000, height=1000, bg="white")
rootFrame.pack()
canvas = Tkinter.Canvas(rootFrame, width=1000, height=1000, bg="white")
canvas.pack()
```

this is the function that draw the rectangle on canvas :

```
def draw(self, **kwargs):
    id = Rectangle.draw(self, **kwargs)
    canvas.addtag_withtag(self.name, id)
    p = self.center()
    tags = kwargs.get('tags', [])
    tags.append('text')
    tags.append(self.name)
    canvas.create_text(p.x, p.y, text=self.name, font="Consolas 7 bold", tags=tags)
```

Comment: 1. The error message is not connected to any line in the code you show. I am guessing but it could appear in the first line of the function "draw". Please show the whole error message. 2. Try removing most of the lines in draw. post draw with only the lines causing the error. 3. What is self, Rectangle, what does center, what is tags; is canvas the canvas shown above? Try removing most of those variables instead of explaining them iff they are not used by the error. 4. Try to accept answers or comment on the problem with the answer. Otherwise less people are willing to answer.